# jQuery Array is not posting to ASP.NET MVC controller

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I am having a hard time posting a list of arrays from my view to the controller. Every other value is coming through.

Can someone spot what is wrong with my code?

Controller:

```
public ActionResult SaveProgress(BBCRMSurveyVM model)
{
    try
    {
        return Json(new { success = true });
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        return Json(new { success = false, msg = e.Message });
    }
}
```

Main view model:

```
public string ImplementationProcessFeelWasSuccessful { get; set; }
public string ImplementationProcessAdviceOtherFederations { get; set; }
public List<AdditionalTechnologyVM> AdditionalTech = new List<AdditionalTechnologyVM>();
```

AdditionalTechVM:

```
public class AdditionalTechnologyVM
{
    public string PlatformName { get; set; }
    public string BusinessPurpose { get; set; }
    public bool? FullyIntegrated { get; set; }
    public bool? PartiallyIntegrated { get; set; }
}
```

JS file:

```
function onAddButtonClickEvent() {
    additionaltechs.push({
       'PlatformName': platformNameAT,
       'BusinessPurpose': businessPurposeAT,
       'FullyIntegrated': integrated == "Fully" ? true : false,
       'PartiallyIntegrated': integrated == "Partially" ? true : false
    });
}

function SaveProgress() {
    var formData = $('#wizard').serializeArray();

    //if (additionaltechs.length > 0) {
    //    for (var x = 0; x < additionaltechs.length; x++) {
    //        formData[formData.length] = { name: "AdditionalTech", value: JSON.stringify(additionaltechs[x]) };
    //    }
    //}

    formData[formData.length] = { name: "AdditionalTech", value: additionaltechs };

    $.each(formData, function (index, field) {
        if (field.name.search('Budget') > 0) {
            field.value = field.value.replace('$', '').replace(/,/g, '');
        }
    });

    formData = JSON.stringify(formData);

    console.log(formData);
    
    $.ajax({
        url: '/save-progress',
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        type: 'POST',
        data: formData,
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function () {},
        error: function () {}
    });
}
```

The output in the console:

[image]

The list count is always 0?

Comment: Please post your controller code as well. It will help us identify the receiving method signature

Comment: Sorry about that. Just did

Answer (score 0):

I think you made this more complicated than you needed it to be. :)

Ultimately, it looks like your controller method is taking a single model, not an array.  Thus, I would suspect to see the JSON you send look like this:

```
{
 "ImplementationProcessFeelWasSuccessful" : "",
 "ImplementationProcessAdviceOtherFederations" : "",
 "AdditionalTech" : [...]
}
```

If it should be a single item being sent, then I'd expect your code to be like this:

```
function SaveProgress() {

    var formData =
    {
     ImplementationProcessFeelWasSuccessful : $('#wizard #val1').val(),
     ImplementationProcessAdviceOtherFederations : $('#wizard #val2').val(),
     AdditionalTech :  additionaltechs 
         };

    formData = JSON.stringify(formData);

    console.log(formData);
    
    $.ajax({
        url: '/save-progress',
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        type: 'POST',
        data: formData,
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function () {},
        error: function () {}
    });
}
```

However, you are sending an array of items up and that makes no sense here.

Answer (score -2):

Ended up sending the list as a JSON string & receiving it also as a string. In the controller I using the JsonConvert.DeserializeObject method like this:

```
var additionalTechs = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<AdditionalTechnologyVM>> 
(model.AdditionalTech);
```

Comment: This is deffinetly the way your are NOT supposed to do it.

Comment: This is not elegant or a good practice. You need to receive a List<Model> in your Controller instead. MVC object binding is very intelligent and it perfectly maps if you send the right object via ajax.

Comment: I understand but it did not work. Not sure what the issues was but it would not pass the list to the model. This work around works perfectly fine. the fact that its not an elegant  solution does not make it a bad approach. Got the job done!